# Exercise for six pack abs

Tags: workout-routines, exercise-technique, abdominals

I want to have six pack abs and I am doing 6 different exercises for that. But none of them more than 10 times. Is it sufficient or do I need to increase the number of repetitions?

Could anyone please guide me to the correct video which shows the necessary exercises for getting a six pack. I searched youtube and they have all kinds of different exercises. I can't do all of them.

Comment: Consider this thread: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast

Comment: Focus more on nutrition and less on specific exercise routines.  Get your body fat down to about 8% and you'll see your abs.

Comment: You might list the exercises you're currently doing to make it easier for someone to suggest alterations. There's no "one right way" to do it, but there might be some improvements.

Comment: @Ryan Miller That's really helpful comment; +1.

Comment: @Nathan Wheeler These are the exercise I am doing http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=107375915980587&comments

Comment: I removed the link from the question as the privacy settings to the video changed. Damn you _link rot_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my exercise routine:

1. Wake up after a good nights rest
2. Walk myself into the kitchen and
   cook a healthy breakfast
3. Pack a healthy lunch to eat while at
   work
4. Hit the gym/dojo on the way home
   from work
5. Eat a healthy dinner and don't snack
   too much before going to bed
6. Get to bed early enough to get a
   good night's rest

Success! Notice that my exercise "routine" has more to do with what I eat and how much I sleep to let my body recover than it does with how many reps I do and what exercises I perform. Getting 6-pack abs requires 90% dedication to a healthy diet and lifestyle and 10% use of the correct exercises.

Get up off the floor and stop doing those crunches. Now get yourself into the kitchen and make yourself an egg white omelet.

Comment: Most trainers, as Sparafusile mentions, seem to suggest eating a lot of egg whites. I have seen recommendations of 10 a day.

Comment: I could never stomach 10 a day. I could eat 2 or 3 and still enjoy them however.

Comment: I never knew that diet could play such an important role. +1

Comment: Diet plays the most important role. You can get a six pack without exercising, but you can't get one without eating right.

Comment: @Chris The key is finding sources of lean protein. Eggs, tuna, edamame, beans (not refried), chicken. The key I use is to look at the fat/protein ratio. You can also cut fat out of otherwise fatty foods. For instance, with beef, drain off the fat after browning hamburger and make your own beef jerky by dehydrating lean cuts. Of course, you also need to consider cutting carbs and processed food out of your diet as much as possible. A high carb diet will set you back more than anything.

Comment: @Evan Just to provide an anecdotal counter example, in the past year, I started eating low carb with tons of fat. I eat the fatty parts of steak instead of cutting it off. Delicious. This, plus crossfit, has led to the first six pack of my (extremely athletic) life.

Comment: @michael Let me clear that up. I'm not saying *all* fat is bad. Fat is a great source of energy and *healthy* fats are good for the heart and circulatory system. I was only trying to say that *lean* protein works better for **cutting** down your fat%. Personally, I would have a nice six pack right now (without any crunches) but I recently switched to consuming more whole cottage cheese and whole milk to maintain my fat%. Why? because it's easier to build muscle when you have a little fat. I don't like the energy troughs from cutting too much.

Comment: @Evan And I am hypothesizing that all natural fat is good fat. I am also disagreeing that lean protein will make a person leaner. But, all I have is anecdotal evidence: I also drink whole milk and eat tons of cheese, both of which are new to me this year.

Comment: @michael Yea... I wish somebody would finally do a conclusive study on the relationship between consumption of dietary fat and body fat%. Especially since the conventional stance toward cholesterol has been dis-proved. Unfortunately, no such study exists (that I know of). I say *lean* protein to play it safe and because it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: @Evan Plaice Thanks for the recommendation, could you please guide me some other food items rich in lean protein, because I am 100% vegeterian. :-)

Comment: @Chris: Beans, nuts, tofu, and some whole grains. You can also use a protein supplement if you need more.

Answer (score 2):

I know you will not like this answer, but here it goes anyway:

You do not need direct ab work to have a six-pack. Focus on core lifts and watch your diet. You will not believe what some squats and deadlifts can do for your 6-pack.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum mass gain I would recommened 15 reps each set. It is also very important to have a low fat percantage - under 12-10% should be sufficient. There are a LOT of different exercises for the abs. I would recommened you to vary between a lot. Variation is good. Some exercises focus more on the upper part than others, while some focus more on the side. You should mix so that you do exercies that trains the whole pack.

Answer (score 1):

As most people are saying, it's really important to watch your diet and exercise more generally than just your abs, but if you want a hard ab workout try [P90X Ab Ripper X](http://www.freeworkoutguides.com/workoutguides/p90x-ab-ripper-workout). There are 11 moves and you do 25 reps each - and there is a good mix of moves for upper abs, lower abs, and obliques. That first link has the first half of the 15 minute video along with a description of the moves. Here's the link to [Part 1](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1464945638519938565) and [Part 2](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=97404099147633519) on Youtube.

Also check out [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/looking-for-short-home-routine-for-thighs-and-abs/3744#3744) for more ab workout options.

Answer (score 0):

There are many individuals who have very well developed abs, but they don't have a six pack. This is because, as many other answers mention, the nutrition plays a key role.

Showing a six pack implies that the muscles are visible, and therefore that you limit the amount of fat on your abdomen. So in my opinion the main thing you should focus on is exercise that helps burn fat, not necessary localized muscle building. Try to incorporate running in your routine.
Boxing can also be an activity with great benefits for you: it has many elements of cardio training combined with moves that seriously sculpt your abs and back.