# Help with obtaining torso abs

Tags: diet, muscle, cardio, abdominals

I was wondering how I might be able to obtain abs. I would already say I have a lifestyle suited to gaining them. Every day of the week apart from Monday (rest day) I go running/biking anywhere from 2 - 8 miles in the morning. In the afternoon and evening I do some ab work outs, which include 50 crunches, 20 leg raises, 25 twists and 25 vertical leg crunches. I repeat this again later in the evening which doubles the amount I previously stated.

As for diet, for breakfast I have Weetabix cereal before the morning cardio exercise. For lunch sandwiches with low fat butter and cheese, with lettuce, fruit smoothie, yogurt and two other fruits. I also include a bit of a treat so a bit of dark chocolate or a cookie. Dinner isn't as good to be honest I'm a fussy eater so for years I've been having processed foods such as potato waffles and nuggets and things like that. Although recently I've been including fresh fish and peas/green beans sometimes broccoli/cauliflower to replace some of the processed foods. Also sometimes plain pasta. For dessert I have a yogurt and another fruit such as strawberry's or tinned pineapple and then another small treat such as a cookie. Every Saturday we have a take away for dinner, but that's fine, once a week isn't too bad.

Another thing to add is that any food I have is very simple, no sauces no fillings. For example If I have a beef burger, it will be bread and simply the beef nothing else. That sort of thing.

I'm very good with drinks, never had fizzy drinks in my life nor alcohol. For 21 years (my age) I've lived on water, milk, black current juice and orange juice.  I hate fizzy drinks and alcohol. And I drink about a galleon of water a day. Also I've never smoked in my life.

As said before I'm 21, I weigh around 135/140 lbs I'm about 175 cm's/5 foot 9. I am very skinny, just no muscle, and I'm wondering how I can get some small abs on my torso, not to show off or anything just so i have a reduced risk of having belly fat later in life. I've been sticking to this lifestyle for around 2 years now and it doesn't seem to be doing any good in terms of torso abs. Also If it effects anything I have mild/high functioning Autism but I doubt that effects my physical health. If anyone can point out anything I'm doing wrong please let me know.

Thanks GR412.

Comment: Other similar questions: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/exercise-for-six-pack-abs/2753#2753

http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast?lq=1

Comment: The lower your body fat percentages, the more visible your abs will show with those exercises. Also, the intensity of the exercises are important. Abs exercises are not cardio exercises...... ***go slow with the reps.***

Comment: @Alec what do you mean?

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. There are similar questions already asked, which have been answered. You might benefit from reading them.