# Chubbyness from the face and body

Tags: exercise, body-fat

I am 26 years old male. I exercise, run etc but my chubbiness wont just go especially from the face as you can see. Any good suggestions? So I can look more rugged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best exercise to lose belly fat fast](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of many things. Overall if your body fat % is high, your face will be a obvious representation of that no matter how much you run, workout etc. Also it could be your diet. More specifically the sodium/carb intake within your diet and hydration. Cut back on the salts and increase you're hydration and see if that can't take off some of the water weight in your face. Also if you are experimenting with AAS (prob not), then this will also add to water bloat in the face. More so in aromatizing compounds such as Testosterones, and other non DHT derived compounds.

You want a rugged face ? Lose fat. Lose the salt. Lose the carbs.

Good luck !

Comment: Hi Macedon thanks for reply. What's AAS? And does 'salt' makes a person's face look fat?

Comment: When you eat foods high in sodium, you disturb your normal balance of sodium and potassium, which affects your kidney's ability to filter excess water from your bloodstream. As a result, your body holds on to water that it would have otherwise expelled through urine.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you are really asking is ***How do I lose 'that stubborn weight'***

## Let’s start off with a simple fact:

There is no magic pill  to weight loss or to looking great and being fit,  it takes hard work, dedication and commitment. The dedication and commitment extend far beyond just going to the gym and working hard, fitness is a lifestyle, remember abs are made in the kitchen.

## Eat Clean:

> "The focus of eating foods without preservatives and artificial sweeteners."

Being 26 years old up until this point you most likely were able to consume just about anything and maintain a decent figure, now things are starting to change, and your desk job is working its magic... *it's time to start to change yourself.*  It's unlikely that your exercise program will overcome any bad stuff you put in your body throughout the day so change the way you eat, eat clean.

A great rule of thumb is try to do the majority of your shopping on the  outside perimeter of the grocery store.  Most of the time the items in the isles are filled with all sorts of artificial sweeteners and are highly processed.  When you do have to visit the isles, take the extra minute to make good selections, you will thank yourself later.

## Eat more frequently:

While this sounds a bit counterproductive the idea is simple.  Eat at least 5 -6 small meals per day.  Your meals should be well balanced and spaced evenly, which lends itself to you eating about every 2-3 hours daily.  When you incorporate this into your daily dietary regimen, your [TEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_dynamic_action) increases, which in turn,  results in an increased metabolism, reduced hunger, more energy and essentially converts to weight loss.

Don’t confuse eating more frequently with eating more though, your meals need to be smaller. You are basically eat the same amount you did before but spreading it out across the day.

## Portion Control:

> “The understanding how much a serving size of food is and how many calories or how much food energy a serving contains”

By understanding and applying the proper portions to each meal you won't over eat.  That’s right - even by eating your fruits and vegetables you can have to much of a good thing.  There are a number of online [calculators](http://iifym.com/iifym-calculator/) you can use to help you with determining the proper amount of cabs, protein, fiber, calories etc you should be receiving.

## Exercise:

It sounds like you are doing well in this area, but for other readers of this post: Weight training and regular exercise are just as important to incorporate in your daily routine as clean eating, portion control, and keeping hydrated .  Regular exercise has shown to have a number of health advantages, but let’s just focus on burning excess calories.  When you exercise you exert some amount of energy. This energy comes from the fuel you put in your body ( we gotta have good fuel ), or the stored fuel, also known as fat, that we carry around.  So by carefully crafting a diet plan so we don’t consume too many calories, and adding regular 30 minute workouts into our day, we are able to call on those fat cells to keep us going, in turn helping us lose weight.

Comment: Nope, meal frequency does not affect the TEF. The laws of thermodynamics won't change no matter how often you eat a day. Increasing meal frequency might be a good _lifestyle_ choice for some, though, as it could be easier to stick to a diet that way.

Comment: Eating clean is also a myth, calories in vs calories out.

Comment: Eating clean is about providing good fuel for your body, far from a myth. If you eat candy bars all day you will be starving your body of the nutrients it needs to do the best at what it does. I agree with calories in vs out logic although clean eating promotes making the most out of the ones you do consume and limits empty calories.