# Losing body fat

Tags: training, body-fat

I am a 16 yo girl that has gained abit of weight the last year. I am a dancer and dance very often, but quite as I said, a year ago.

I am 1.58 (5'2.5) and weight 53kg (120 lbs). I am not overweight but I am as I like to call it, skinnyfat. I have extra body fat I would lik to lose! I'm usually a 110 - 115 lbs.

I've been running everyday for 9 days and I've seen great result on my belly but I still weight the same! I also have very strong calves and thighs, but they've always been very muscular.

My question is, how can I change my diet to lose body fat? I love love love bread, rice and pasta and have atleast a slice of bread everyday. But I tried cutting out fatty meat, bread and such for about two months now. This does not work out with my hair and nails. I lose alot of hair in the shower, and my nails have been splitting and breaking for weeks now. 
My hair is usually very strong and silky, and my nails are also very very strong.

And how do I teach myself to eat smaller portions? I tend to over eat alot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best exercise to lose belly fat fast](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast)

Comment: Believe it or not, using a smaller plate, cup or bowl leads to smaller portions. ["One cup of food on a small plate looks like more than the same cup of food on a large plate."](http://www.choosemyplate.gov/weight-management-calories/weight-management/better-choices/decrease-portions.html).  Breads, rice and pasta are all carbs and are broken down in the body to sugar.  If you are cutting carbs and fats you are cutting the two of the three sources of fuel.  This site does not really address diet and nutrition.  You may want to try [SparkPeople](http://www.sparkpeople.com/) for more diet info.