# How to keep full face

Tags: weight-loss

Few years back I was 110lbs at 5'4" . I was able to eat any junk, tiny clothes fit but face was skinny and I needed makeup to look healthy.

Life happened I am nearly 140lbs. Only good part is face filled up and it looks much better --- no need for makeup!

Now I am been exercising, i.e. challenging myself to lift heavier weights, do more intensive cardio, etc.

Takes about 30 min a day, and when done I feel I got a super workout --- plus I watch what I eat (if I even have appetite ...)

Question --- how to keep same full face while burning the extra fat and strengthening muscles? Is this even an issue? Or will it take care of itself considering I am doing arm and shoulder exercise?

Please advise.

Comment: Just as you can't target where you want to lose weight, there's no way to control whether your face will remain "full".  There are too many other factors involved, the least of which, is doing arm and shoulder exercises.

Comment: Drink alcohol, get a nice puffy face?

Comment: I don't touch the alcohol

Comment: Your problem is called *aging*. Welcome on board, Sir. Forget about your face. Keep on with your workouts and you will have a slim face but full of character. Much better than being an aged fatty couch potato.

Comment: @Mephisto I am a `ma'am`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best exercise to lose belly fat fast](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast)

Comment: @SeanDuggan How is this a duplicate? My question is how to KEEP fat on a body part, not lose it!

Comment: @SohniMahiwal
Targeted fat loss. We get it fairly often for different body parts. As I recall correctly, that's the usual one we point people to to indicate that there really is no such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to keep same full face while burning the extra fat and strengthening muscles?**

I think I have a rough idea as to what you mean by "full face", but to answer your question, **no**. If you are in a caloric deficit (aka eating less), then chances are you will lose some fat on your face whereas if you are in a caloric surplus (aka eating more), then chances are you will gain some fat on your face.

The problem is that you **cannot spot reduce fat**, hence you cannot maintain that "full face". It is **not possible to burn fat while gaining strength / muscle mass** at your current height and weight.

As for now, you should not worry too much about your face, and continue **lean bulking**(eating in a small caloric surplus aka just **eat more than you usually do**).

Comment: Will make sure I  eat small caloric surplus. I guess it's a balance.