# How to reduce Weight?

Tags: weight-loss

I am 24 year old male, my height is 5'9" and weight is around 80 kg.

How can I reduce it to around 65 kg in short span of time (around 6 months)

Will Protein powder help in reducing my weight?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Or http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast

Comment: Can you expand on your build? I am 5ft5 and 82kg  and I would consider a eight of 65kg to be extremely lean (<10% body fat), this would be unpleasant/extremely hard to aim for in that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a steady calorie deficit. How you achieve this deficit is up to you - you can exercise to burn them off, or you can change your diet to achieve a deficit - or even better, both.

15kg in 6 months isn't far fetched at all. I suggest logging your meals through myfitnesspal or similar(and be honest with yourself) and aim at a calorie deficit of around 400-500 calories per day.

**Is Protein powder will help you in reducing my weight?**

That's impossible to say. It can assist you in recovering after workouts and get a better proportion of protein. But again.. You need a goal and stay calculated, and not chug down protein shakes without a purpose. Because no, they don't magically burn off extra fat or anything.

Comment: Increased protein consumption can increase satiety which can make it easier to go longer between meals, which in turn can make it easier to decrease overall caloric intake. So protein *can* help in that regard. But like you say, it won't do anything in terms of burning fat on its own.

Comment: To follow up on your comment, which I agree on: Diets aren't magical, what some diets do is the lessen your need/desire for more food than you actually need, i.e. a ketogenic diet, when I was on it, made me not really be hungry at all(and I LOVE food). I simply had to remind myself that it was time for dinner, whereas I, on a normal diet that include both carbs and fat, would have a rolling stomache by 5:30pm in the afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to lose weight:

Calories in < Calories used up

Use tools like IIFYM.com, myfitnesspal and Stronglifts 5x5 to calculate how to plan your diet, track your intake and work out.

Answer (score 0):

create a calorie deficit .
thats it.either through eating less or moving more or the combination of both.
Fist step is to figure out your TDEE(total daily energy expenditure)
There are many calculators online.Google for them and get your number.
Cut your calorie intake by a few hundred calories. Make sure that number is sustainable that you feel ok with that amount of food.
Protein powders dont help weight loss at all. They are a powdered form of food . that's it.
Its important to get in a certain amount of protein a day to minimize muscle loss .(once again you can google for the amount as there are various opinions)

If you have a hard time hitting that number protein powders are your friend