# Why is my belly fat so loose/watery/un-rigid?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, bellyfat

I have been working out for the past 9 months and I have lost around 30kg. I started at 130kg and now I am at 100kg but at the same time I have built up a lot of muscle in my arms, back, chest, and legs.

My waist measurements have shrunk a lot but the shape of that region is still not nice and I see excess fat that is very 'watery'. It feels like I am carrying a sack of water around and it does not seem to go away. I understand that this is the hardest fat to get rid off but I would like to know how common/typical is this situation and why it is so watery unlike in the past or unlike some other parts of the body where fat is more rigid.

Except for good diet and exercise what other tips are there to improve this situation?

Comment: For in-depth analysis of the composition of belly fat verses other fatty deposits, BiologySE might be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Belly fat is not unlike fat in other deposits on the body. It's just that the belly has a larger deposit, so its viscosity (or lack thereof) is more noticeable due to the volume.

Additionally, abdominal muscles aren't very large to begin with, so the layer of fat on top of it will seem softer.

For information on how to get rid of belly fat, see this answer: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/870/8828