# I can't swallow CLA pills, looking for alternatives

Tags: supplements, bellyfat

I have too much belly fat and trying to burn them. But because of my chronic sinusitis (it's affecting my throat) I'm not able to swallow CLA pills, they are too big. I see that there are no liquid CLA. I'm looking for an alternative to CLA to achieve my goal (burning belly fat). I used L-Carnitine but didn't see any improvement. Which supplement should I take to help burning my belly fat?

**My Body**

Height: 179 cm.

Weight: 86 kg.

I don't have any hearth problem but I didn't take any test about it.

I have scoliosis so I'm not able to do basic belly fat burning movements (like sit-ups) properly.

**My Workout Routine**

I'm going to GYM at least 2 times in a week. Usually starting with light cardio for warming, and then working with weights and then finishing with intense running & cycling.

**Update 1**

Actually I've lost about 9 kilograms in 3 months by going to gym regularly. I was 95 kilograms before starting to exercises. But now my weight lost is really slow and I'm not losing weight anymore. I know weight can be same because I'm gaining muscles while losing fat but body proportion not changing. My belly fat and chest fat are still there  There is no visible progress. Because of this I'm think it's time to start taking some helpers.

Comment: Supplements won't help you here. The thing is your body has fully adapted to your current exercise. You need a concept called "periodization". For the next 3 months, do no gym, run instead, then when you hit another plateau, switch it up again, maybe focus on swimming for 3 months, the go back to the gym.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best exercise to lose belly fat fast](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast)

Answer (score 4):

You may not like to hear this but a pill is not your answer. You cannot spot reduce belly fat. Exercising one muscle group (such as your abs) can increase muscle in a specific area but fat is lost all over your body, not in one area.

Doing all the ab exercise in the world will only result in a visible 6 pack for people who are relatively lean. There is no such thing as an obese person with a well defined 6 pack although some obese powerlifters (for example) have significant ab muscle (that is covered up with fat).

Keep eating at a deficit to your TDEE and exercising. You will lose weight all over your body, including your belly area.

I ran your stats and your BMI is 26.8 so you are not obese (just marginally overweight). Your goal is obtainable with more hard work (diet and exercise). No pills are needed!

http://www.myheart.org.sg/article/hearty-tools/tools/bmi-calculator/239

Comment: Actually I've lost about 9 kilograms in 3 months by going to gym regularly. I was 95 kilograms before starting to exercises. But now my weight lost is really slow and I'm not losing weight anymore. I know weight can be same because I'm gaining muscles while losing fat but body proportion not changing. My belly fat and chest fat are still there :) There is no visible progress. Because of this I'm think it's time to start taking some *helpers*.

Comment: @Eray the law of diminishing returns is applicable to reducing body-fat percentage. The lower you get, the harder it is to reduce by the same amount. Going from 28 to 23% body-fat is infinitely easier than 23 to 18%.

Comment: This is all irrelevant to the question asked. Although I personally agree with what you're saying, it would be better to link a relevant question on the effectiveness of CLA or  spot-reducing in a comment or suggest that op ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The real question you seem to be asking is how to lose the remaining weight. [Yao Choa raises multiple good points in their answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/31264/18169):

1. A pill is not the answer
2. You cannot target fat loss areas: you can only improve muscle in a single area

It's likely you want to look at what you're eating (i.e. how many calories per day) and changing your routine. It's best to seek a professional's help on this matter, and as you are already going to the gym a PT should be able to help you out (some PT's have special training in nutrition, but it's likely most PT's have good information regardless). It helps to track what you are eating, and there are plenty of mobile apps that can aid this. Make sure you aren't eating more than you need to, but also make sure you aren't starving yourself (it doesn't help: your body will just store fat instead)

Consider also measuring your fat% instead of weight. Again, a PT should be able to help you do this, but it's possible to do alone. This statistic is a better one to measure rather than weight, because as you point out you will put on weight due to muscle.

If you have a high muscle% (>40%) you can likely drop the weights altogether and focus on HIIT. A PT could help with this further, but you probably want 3 high-intense training sessions per week.

Comment: Dear Tas, Thank you for your detailed answer and I totally agree with you. But I won't stop going to GYM and I'm not expecting miracles from a pill, I just want to know if there are any nutritions to accelerate burning speed of my fats *while/after/before I'm doing my regular exercises*.

Comment: Sorry, I never meant to imply not go to the gym. You absolutely 100% should continue going! As far as nutrients go, you could look into protein supplements (whey isolate) _if_ you aren't getting enough protein in your diet. If you find it difficult to get 50g+ of protein a day, whey isolate as a post-workout for extra protein should aid fat loss. Like most things: avoid ones you can buy at supermarkets.

Comment: Will proteins help burning fat?

Comment: Indirectly: it can help build muscle, which aids fat loss. I'm not convinced there's a pill or nutrient to help reduce fat

Comment: CLA helping to reduce fat? Am I wrong?

Comment: Like I said: I'm not convinced. I've certainly never uncovered a study that shows it works.

Answer (score 0):

CLA is available in powdered form.
This can be ingested by simply mixing with water and drinking.

[Example available here](http://www.bulkpowders.ie/cla-powder.html)

Comment: Answers the title but not the question inside: "Which supplement should I take to help burning my belly fat?"

Comment: @JJosaur That question seeks an alternative after falsely assuming that no non-tablet CLA is available. Either the question of a suitable supplement remains or the question becomes about fat loss or spot reducing and should be closed as duplicate

Comment: Actually @Niall is right. I've decided to use CLA and start looking for a powder or liquid form. Or other supplement instead of CLA. Others answers not answering my actual question but providing really good informations about my problem (belly fat) . I'm not sure which one should I accept as answer.

Comment: BTW, *Bulk Powders* brand is not selling in my country (Turkey)

Comment: @Eray It was just an example to prove that it exists. With a bit of research you might find someone who delivers powder to Turkey. Failing that you could try a shipito.com type service or even get powder in gelcaps and empty the powder out and use like suggested above. Best of luck

Comment: According to our custom laws, all sport powders / drinks (like protein powders, aminos) for individuals are forbidden. So I'm looking for another alternatives maybe I can find in my country. There is no CLA powder in Turkey (I did a research). @Niall

Answer (score -1):

Milk from grassfed cows has lots of CLA. At least if you do eat butter the best solution is to switch to "grassfed butter" like Kerry Gold.