# What is the best gym routine for Indians to get flat stomach.?

Tags: diet, gym, abdominals, stomach

We Indians are very crazy about food though we know that can affect our body. I want to know what will be the best diet and gym routine for Indians to get good muscles and flat stomach.

There are various similar posts on SO about fat loss, but I need answer particularly for Indians.

Comment: While being Indian may affect your dietary choices, the advice is still the same: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body

Comment: You should say: for people who likes to eat, because it can concern not only Indians.

Comment: Indians are also humans. Their body will respond the same way to food as anyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

We're all different, but the good news is we're not so different that you need a special routine because you're Indian. There are specific foods which are harder to tolerate for some groups than others (for example, northern Europeans can digest cow's milk more easily than most other people), but there will also be a significant difference within populations. It could be that you and I (Indian and western European) are more similar than me and my neighbour!

So you could go with just about any no-nonsense advice: eat good food, and not too much. You can, however, never eat too much vegetables (as long as they're not smothered in a fatty sauce). Join a gym and get someone to show you how to lift weights. Lifting weights is one of the most effective weight loss exercises because it will increase the amount of calories you burn while you're *not* exercising.

Keep a food and exercise diary. Track your weight, but more importantly, track how you feel and how you sleep. If you feel great a certain week, check what you ate and how you exercised that week - that's probably what's good for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please provide me some good gym schedule and some chart for calories ? I am very confused about food intake.

Comment: "You can, however, never eat too much vegetables" you can eat too much of anything. With veg it is harder to pile in 1000's of calories but it is possible.

Comment: I started with these 3x a week: https://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/beginner-body-weight-workout-burn-fat-build-muscle/

Comment: As to calories: this is very personal. The usual recommended amount is between 2000-2500 for people that don't work out intensely, but calories in general are an imprecise measure (for example, most foods have variable water content, which influences their mass but not their calories). Try to track what you eat for four weeks and see whether you like the change in body composition. Then add or remove 200-300 calories depending on how you feel. Or keep it the same if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Only good measure to reduce fat is training, train some period of day say 1hr (cardio + training ), you will start reducing fat, it will burn your calories, also at same time control your calorie intake. Both together will reduce your fat and maintain your weight

Comment: Diet is the most important factor in losing weight. One can lose weight by just dieting alone. https://examine.com/faq/how-do-i-lose-fat-around-my-belly