# Mini elliptical machine for slimmer legs

Tags: legs, home-exercise, elliptical

I am looking to buy a MINI Ellipcical machine for home that is good for slimmering legs and butt.

What type of machine should I look for? Is the Step-like machine better than the Biking-like one for legs and butt?

I see this one:
[image]

Or this type:
[image]
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a shopping recommendation, and, any answer would be opinion based.

Comment: It is not a shopping recommendation. Read the post properly. It is about differences in workout body areas between the 2 type of machines.

Comment: "I am looking to buy..." And, "what type of machine should I look for...?" Sounds like shopping recommendation to me.

Comment: Regardless if this is a shopping question or not, the premise has been answered already: [Spot reduction is not a thing](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body)

Comment: I marked this as duplicate because as JJ points out, spot reduction is a myth. However, your basic question is also either a shopping recommendation or personal opinion, i.e. "Which should I buy?" or "Which is better?", all of which got close votes.