# Am I doing abs workout right and how should I check my progress?

Tags: workout, abdominals, progress

I am doing abs workout (7 minute app workout 1-2 per day) for "that slightly muscular sexy abs" for 2 month now, but I don't really see any visual progress and this makes me really sad =(

Should I change my workout / do it more / try more strict diet?

How to to check my progress (to keep my motivation and to be sure I am on the right way)?

1,75m / 80kg / broad shoulders type

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that getting bigger abs isn't going to give you *visible* abs.

Your abdominal muscles are situated behind a layer of fat, which makes them invisible. Any amount of ab workouts isn't going to help you unless you reduce your belly fat.

> Should I change my workout / do it more / try more strict diet?

Yes / no / YES.

The best way to get rid of fat is to take control of your diet. And your workout routine should include your entire body, and not just one part of it.

Any workout program that targets only abs, is a *supplemental* program. Not a full program.

Comment: I don't think it targets abs that hard + I do some exercise as part of my job/daily routine, but what program do you recommend?

Comment: Would appreciate some tips regarding diet too

Comment: There's no shortage of answers to these questions on this site already.

http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body/870#870 - http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body

Comment: As for workout program, try Stronglifts 5x5, or whatever program you see that you like.

Comment: I don't have time or desire for gym and don't really see how you can call it "full program". I'll check those questions through, thanks.

Comment: @Somem8 "everybody wants to look like a bodybuilder but nobody want to lift no heavy-ass weight."

Comment: @Somem8 - Therein lies the problem. If you don't have the desire to go to the gym, then that's the bottle-neck for your progress. If one could get chiseled by little to no effort, then everyone would look like Greek gods.

Comment: I think that it's reasonable for someone to want to target one part of their body, and not do a whole-body workout to get the abs they want. :) That said, since part of the equation is reducing fat, and there's no way to spot-reduce fat (short of liposuction which is now known to be horribly bad for you because the fat that can be removed is the "good fat"), a whole-body workout isn't a bad way to burn the valories.

Comment: :) Just saying, if someone walks into the home improvement store and says they want to remodel their kitchen, disparaging them for not wanting to remodel the entire house isn't going to go over very favorably.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Those are some good points, but I don't think the household analogy applies. A room is a standalone room that is physically separated from the other rooms, and can have its own theme. Working out a single muscle-group (let's say chest as an example) can have dire consequences for your overall well-being because unlike decorating rooms, muscles can directly influence each other.