# What're the best exercise for lower body in home?

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding

I'd like to lose some fat in my lower body and exercise some muscle. But, due to intense activity, I rarely hit the gym. I think there must be some workout that I can do in my house/anywhere possible.

My objective is to lose fat in inner thighs, buttocks, and lower abdomen. So, what workouts can I do without any gym equipment?

Comment: You may want to refine your question.  The idea of reducing fat in only some areas is covered in many questions like this one: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body and generally gets questions closed as a duplicate.

Comment: How about stepping "out of the house" and doing a bit of cardio (jogging etc)?

Comment: @gwaigh well, my question more like indoor training to train lower body without any/less gym equpment.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNl9USmMqeM

Comment: I feel like there are two questions here, one about spot reduction of fat, which is addressed by the Duplicate, and one about what exercises target muscle in the inner thighs, buttocks, and lower abdomen (or perhaps build muscle in contrasting areas to make those areas seem smaller), which is not addressed by this.

Answer (score -1):

I would couple squats with lunges and hip thrusts however building muscle is not equivalent to losing fat. To lose fat you must be in a caloric deficit through either dieting, cardio or a combination. Do both exercise and cardio and your legs will look great.