# How to reduce weight around my abdominal area when I have liver cirrhosis?

Tags: running, exercise, diet, intermittent-fasting

I have advanced liver disease and weight loss is suggested to me
Need to reduce 20 kgs , most of my body fat is around abdominal region
What diets I need to follow along with exercises .
I am also doing Intermittent Fasting basically skipping dinner .
I am 28 Male and I don't drink alcohol.

Comment: Spot reduction is a myth, and there are a few posts on here already such as [this one](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body?rq=1), Also, with your history this is really something that you need to consult professionals on. We wish you luck on your journey, and if you have questions about specific exercises and similar we can certainly answer those!